# Appear at the bottom of a blank UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm in a viewController add another viewController (a chat interface) of view and its childViewController. The question is: in the chat interface between navigationbar appeared a blank, I do not know how it happened. When I set "navigationController? .navigationBar.translucent = True" becomes such an effect (see gif action figure)
[image: navigationController? .navigationBar.translucent = True]
[image: navigationController? .navigationBar.translucent = false]

Answer (score 0):

[image]I need to know which use case your image describes. "navigationController? .navigationBar.translucent = false"?

You can try to set the top constraint of the view to Top Layout Guide = 0

Comment: I do not know how to do it, you can show it to me pls?

Comment: I dot not use storyBoard or xib, self.view.addSubView(chatVC.view) self.addChildViewController(chatVC)

Comment: can you upload sample of your project in github?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have to solve this problem, just after loading the finished child-controllers to manually adjust the child views frame.origin.y

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem

```
 let chat = ChatViewController(conversationType: RCConversationType.ConversationType_PRIVATE, targetId: currentId)
    currentVC = chat
    self.addChildViewController(chat)
    self.view.addSubview(chat.view)
    chat.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    chat.view.frame.origin.y = -64
```